# Remote desktop without port forwarding

Tags: remote-desktop

I am hoping to set up a way that I can remotely connect and control my Macbook pro remotely even if my mac is currently sleeping. The hitch is I am currently a student which means my computer is generally on wifi that I dont have admin privileges to.

How can I do remote desktop on macos without being able to port forward?

Comment: You can't connect to a sleeping computer.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sure, you just need a way to wake it up first. "Wake on LAN" is definitely a thing – Macbooks support it for Wi-Fi as well. I think Windows alsoprograms Ethernet cards to wake the system on TCP SYN packets if you choose "wake on pattern match" (I never got it to work though).

Comment: @grawity Yeah, but "my computer is generally on wifi that I dont have admin privileges to." That rules out WoL.